# What is the Difference Between LIKE and CONTAINS[cd]?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I can create a predicate `"something LIKE %@"` or I can use `"something CONTAINS[cd] %@"`.

What is the difference between the two forms.

Answer (score 8):

`LIKE` allows for wildcard comparisons while `CONTAINS` does not.

`"Steve Martin" contains "Martin`"

evaluates to true but:

```
"Steve Martin" contains "Martini"
```

... does not but:

```
"Steve Martin" like "Martin*"
```

... does evaluate as true.

`LIKE` allows for more complex comparison and `MATCHES` allows for regex comparisons.